# Format Date in Javascript/JQuery as Single Digit Day

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently, I am pulling in a json feed from our calendar. It brings back the date in the yyyy/mm/dd format... I know I can overwrite this format by using javascript but how would I do this? I need the output to only be the "dd" not the month nor the year.

I would also like single digit days to show up as i.e. "1","2","3","4" and of course dbl digits to show up as usual "10", "11", "12", etc. Any ideas on how I could achieve this reformatting of the date via javascript/jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Date object

```
var theDate = new Date(dateString);

var theDay = parseInt(theDate.getDate(), 10);
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the object and can expect the same string back each time:

```
var theDay = parseInt(dateString.split('/')[2], 10);
```

Comment: Thanks Bic. Ok. would i need to create a function? or would just these var's do the trick?

Comment: @Teemu, nevermind. I was wrong. I thought OP wanted padding :)

Comment: @Teemu Both solutions work [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSnmg/)

You can have the code standalone or in a method, depending on if you need to use it in more than one place. Would need to see your code for context on which might be the better solution.

Comment: @Bic Looks like I'd better go to bed, ofcourse they work, `parseInt()` drops the leading zero...

Answer (score 0):

This code should do it . . .

```
var jsonDate = <...reference to the JSON date value...>;
var dayValue = jsonDate.split("/")[2].replace(/0(.)/, "$1");
```

You've already got a string value, so might as well just manipulate it as a string.

- `jsonDate.split("/")[2]` splits up the full date and then takes the third item from the resulting array (i.e., the day value)
- `.replace(/^0(.)$/, "$1")` will trim off the "0", if it finds it in the first position of the "day" string

Then you just use `dayValue` wherever you need to use it.   :)

**UPDATE:**

Based on the comments below, try using this as your code:

```
var listingEl = $('<div class="eventListings" title="' + item.event.title + '" />');
var dateEl = $('<div class="mdate">' + dayValue + '</div>');
var linkEl = $('<a href="' + item.event.localist_url + '" />');
var titleEl = $('<div class="mcTitle">' + item.event.title + '</div>');

linkEl.append(titleEl);
listingEl.append(dateEl);
listingEl.append(linkEl);
$('#localistTitle').append(listingEl);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

There was something not working in your code (I think the main issues was how you were using `.appendTo()`).  I split it out into a multi-step process and used `.append()` instead.  It worked correctly when I tested it locally.

Comment: So my reference to the dayValue would be something like this:
var jsonDate = item.event.first_date;
 var dayValue = jsonDate.split("/")[2].replace(/0(.)/, "$1");

Comment: Yeah . . . if `item.event.first_date` is where the date value is stored, then that is what you would use for that first line.  Alternately, you could combine it into: `var dayValue = item.event.first_date.split("/")[2].replace(/0(.)/, "$1");`  Let me know if you have any questions about what the code is doing, that I didn't answer (like if the regex is confusing).

Comment: <script type="javascript/text">
 var dayValue = item.event.first_date.split("/")[2].replace(/0(.)/, "$1");
</script>

***Doesn't seem to be working... hmmm...

Comment: What's not working?  Are you getting an error?  Is the value wrong?  Is the "0" not being removed?

Comment: Nothing is happening. i took a look in my console and no activity everything looks like its working... this is how im pulling in the date:  $('<div class="eventListings" title="'+item.event.title+'" ><div class="mdate">'+item.event.first_date+'</div><a href="'+item.event.localist_url+'"><div class="mcTitle">'+item.event.title+'</div></a></div>').appendTo('#localistTitle');

Comment: Okay, so put `var dayValue = item.event.first_date.split("/")[2].replace(/0(.)/, "$1");` before that section of code and replace `item.event.first_date` with `dayValue` in your existing code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46034/discussion-between-mizakita-and-talemyn)

Comment: Can't right now . . . chat is blocked by the firewall at work.  :/

Comment: hi.... ok im unsuccessful at getting the format. this is what i have:///////////////////////////////////
var dayValue = item.event.first_date.split("/")[2].replace(/0(.)/, "$1"); ////////////////////////////////

$('<div class="eventListings" title="'+item.event.title+'" ><div class="mdate">'+dayValue+'</div><a href="'+item.event.localist_url+'"><div class="mcTitle">'+item.event.title+'</div></a>

Comment: There is something not working in the code that you are using to create the link . . . I'm looking into it.